# Is it posible that two devices plugged in different PCI slots share single PCI bus

Tags: computer-architecture, pci

Let's assume we have two network cards, Foo and Bar plugged in slots 5 and 4 on motherboard, with some BDF id assigned, for example:

- Foo => **09**:00.0
- Bar => **02**:00.0

That's the usual scenario. But is it possible, that these two devices will share the '*bus*' part, and differ only in '*device*' part, like:

- Foo => **09**:00.0
- Bar => **09**:01.0

While still being plugged under different slots?

Does x86 architecture allows that, do you know any edge case when this would be true?

Maybe multiple PCI slots stacked on single PCI bus, like a hub, or something, is this even possible? I have a limited knowledge in electronics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For conventional PCI, yes. In general, many slots in a conventional PCI system will share the same bus number. This is because all devices on the same bus segment share the same bus number. Conventional PCI is a shared parallel bus, so multiple PCI slots are simply connected in parallel (well, mostly in parallel) to form a bus segment, and all devices on a given bus segment share a bus number and are differentiated by device number.

For PCI express, no. All links in PCI express are serial point-to-point links, so devices cannot share bus numbers unless they are physically on the same end point. Therefore, PCIe cards will in general be assigned a unique bus number and a device number of zero. Device numbers other then zero are only used in a few cases: root complex integrated endpoints, switch downstream ports, and devices that have ARI enabled to merge the device number into the function number so they can use up to 256 functions instead of 8.